# Cassandra Datastax cpp-driver - Callbacks seem to use 1 thread

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am currently using the CassFuture callback future to implement an asynchronous pattern for processing Cassandra queries.  It appears that all of the callbacks are coming in on the same thread.  Is this the expected behavoir?

Comment: can you add a code fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the current version of the driver (v2.9.0) the number of threads is configured via [cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io()](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.9/api/struct.CassCluster/#function-cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io) before creating a session and defaults to **1**. If you increase the number of IO threads in the cluster configuration you will notice that **CassFuture** callbacks will begin to show up on different threads.

**NOTE:** If your callback is slow, consider running on a separate thread; otherwise the callback might block IO operations for other requests being executed on the callback/IO thread. Another recommendation is not use the complete number of cores/virtual cores available in your hardware configuration as this could starve resources from your client application (and potentially from the OS services).

Comment: I had already set the number of io threads to 8 using cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io().  This did not help.  The VM that I am using had 4 cores allocated.  When we increased the number of cores to 8, the system then appeared to start using 8 cores.  I have since set the number of io threads back to 4 and am in the process of creating a pool of worker threads to delegate the work to once the callback has been triggered.  Thanks for the response.